# No longer able to use the Google Sheets Script Editor

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I've been using the Google Sheets Script Editor for a few years now, just as a hobby, for things like making games and calculating taxes. However, as of late, Google seems to be hassling me whenever I try to run a script on a spread sheet. Here are the steps to reproduce:

1. Create a new spreadsheet
2. Go to tools -> Script Editor
3. Paste this code into your script:

`function helloWorld() {
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    sheet.getRange(1,1,1,1).setValue("Hello, World!");
}`

4. Click the "Run" button
5. This dialog shows up, saying I have to review my permissions before running my code:
   [Verification](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tAhdy.png)
6. If you click "Review Permissions", it will ask you to choose an account, and then this condescending dialog will show up telling you to "Go back to safety":
   [This app isn't verified](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gffvv.png)

I am not an "app developer", I am just a hobbyist trying to do my taxes and make games. The last dialog says that I can submit a "verification request", however this looks like it's for larger corporations who develop apps (it asks for a "company name" and some jargon about "OAuth" that I don't understand a word of), and not for hobbyists.

Does this mean that the Sheets Script Editor is no longer something for public use? I've been using it for years now, and I might have better luck writing my own spreadsheet program before I could ever figure out what all of this verification nonsense is.

Would I have to come up with a fake company name and B.S. the whole verification thing just so I can use custom scripts in my personal spreadsheets?

Comment: On that dialog at bottom left, there must be a option to proceed (unsafe) or something, try that. Hopefully that'll work

Comment: Oh yes, I see it under "Advanced". That seemed to work. Thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On that dialog at bottom left, there must be a `Advanced` option and there you'll find proceed (unsafe) or something, try that

I think, getting your apps verified is for production(where other peoples will also use it). If you just want to do a personal project or something as hobby then I guess you can ignore it.

Comment: Advanced link isn't there anymore.